# I need to get product collection by child category in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to get product collection by child category.

Category Structure:

```
Shop  
  Colors 
    Rushmore -- 12 
    Boston Mill 
    Little Cottonwood
```

Here is my code:

```
$colorId = 12 (This is my rushmore id(child id))
    $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
                        $cat = $categoryFactory->create()->load($colorId);
                        $categoryProducts = $cat->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addCategoryFilter($cat);

                        foreach ($categoryProducts as $product){
                            print_r($product->getData());

                            //echo '<span>'.$product_name.'</span>';
                        }
```

Comment: What error you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product collection by category ID would look something like this.

```php
    public function __construct(   
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
       array $data = []
    ){    
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection($categories = [])
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);  
        return $collection;
    }
```